# QTcpSocket reading some extra bytes while reading bulk data?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

I am currently working on Qt GUI application which receives data packets from server (LINUX Server).

In normal cases, its working fine but when bulk amount of data packets has been written by server on socket, client side socket enters into loop to process that data but at the end 8 extra bytes are left which does not belong to my application and application never come out from the loop which makes my application unresponsive.
I am receiving all data without any loss.

My code will clear bit more:

```
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(receiveData()));

void MyClass::receiveData()
{
    char recvbuf[MAXPACKET]; // MAXPACKET = 4096
    char* packet = 0;
    int bytesAvailable = 0;
    int bufSize = MAXPACKET;

    while((bytesAvailable > 0) || tcpSocket ->bytesAvailable())
    {
       if (bytesAvailable == 0 && tcpSocket ->bytesAvailable())
       {
          qint64 requestBytes = bufSize - bytesAvailable;
          bytes = tcpSocket->read(recvbuf + bytesAvailable, requestBytes);
          bytesAvailable += bytes;
       }

       //createPAcket and process Packets method works here
       if (packet)
         processPacket(packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your while condition, you must stop looping and return if bytesAvailable() method says there are no more bytes. There is no quarantee you get data in same chunks it is sent, TCP is stream protocol.

Comment: Perhaps you post some more complete code? In the above, `packet` is always 0, and we can't see what happens to `recvbuf`.

Comment: problem solved. Actually there was delay in writting and reading data chunks and whenever in case server has written let say 4000 bytes and on the other side client is busy processing that data. at the end of 4000 bytes processed, there may be some bytes left let say it may be 4 bytes left which may belong to next packet which does not come on socket yet and system is in while loop. now i am exiting from while and reading that 4 bytes by appending next at the start of next chunk.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your own answer as a solution?